# PHP - xdebug remoto utilizando netbeans

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, debug

**Apresentando o ambiente:**
Tenho um servidor virtual rodando uma distribuição Debian 7.2 (64bits), neste servidor tenho instalado o Apache 2.2.22 e o PHP 5.4.39

Minha máquina hospedeira roda o OS X 10.11, como IDE de desenvolvimento estou utilizando o Netbeans para PHP.

**Explicando o cenário de uso:**
Criei um projeto X que é executado em um servidor remoto, ou seja, na máquina virtual Debian citada logo acima. Nas configurações do projeto defini a opção Executar como Web Site remoto (sftp).

**Descrevendo o problema:**
Instalei o **xdebug**, editei o arquivo **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini** e defini no final do mesmo as configurações abaixo:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

Porém, quando utilizo a opção de depuração do netbeans consigo observar que na barra de status fica a menagem - **Aguardando Conexão (netbeans-xdebug)** - e nada...

Já tentei de tudo mas nada surtiu efeito. Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Comment: Não precisa trocar o localhost pelo ip? na quarta configuração.

Comment: Já tentei isso, defini como 127.0.0.1 e até cheguei a testar o ip da máquina hospedeira, porém, sem sucesso.

Comment: tente trocar xdebug.remote_host=localhost para o ip da sua máquina de desenvolvimento

Comment: também já tentei isso e não surtiu efeito.

Answer (score 2):

Problema resolvido.

No caminho /etc/php5/conf.d o arquivo 20-xdebug.ini deve ser alterado para xdebug.ini e efetuado restart do apache.

Tudo ok agora.